# unrecognized selector sent to instance c# iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uipickerview

Im trying to display a picker view called from a viewdidload method. It compiles fine but at the moment that should display it throws an error. I added a picker called "colorPicker" and a label with the name "colorValueLabel" that should display the selected option in the picker. Thanks

Error:

```
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[PickerDataModel initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1888a9e0
```

This is my Picker class

```
 partial class PickerDataModel : UIPickerViewModel

{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ValueChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// The items to show up in the picker
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> Items { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The current selected item
    /// </summary>
    public string SelectedItem {
        get { return Items [selectedIndex]; }
    }

    int selectedIndex = 0;

    public PickerDataModel ()
    {
        Items = new List<string> ();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called by the picker to determine how many rows are in a given spinner item
    /// </summary>
    public override nint GetRowsInComponent (UIPickerView picker, nint component)
    {
        return Items.Count;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// called by the picker to get the text for a particular row in a particular
    /// spinner item
    /// </summary>
    public override string GetTitle (UIPickerView picker, nint row, nint component)
    {
        return Items [(int)row];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// called by the picker to get the number of spinner items
    /// </summary>
    public override nint GetComponentCount (UIPickerView picker)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// called when a row is selected in the spinner
    /// </summary>
    public override void Selected (UIPickerView picker, nint row, nint component)
    {
        selectedIndex = (int)row;
        if (ValueChanged != null) {
            ValueChanged (this, new EventArgs ());
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the viewdidload method.

```
public partial class DatosPersonalesController : UIViewController
{
    PickerDataModel pickerDataModel;
    ControladorDatosPersonales datosPersonalesController;
    SideBarController sidebar;
    string email;
    string celular;
    string idintranet;
    string tipo;
    string idpersona;
    string os;
    string appversion;

    NoInternetConnectionView noInternetView;

    public DatosPersonalesController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        //inicio picker
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // create our simple picker model
        pickerDataModel = new PickerDataModel();
        pickerDataModel.Items.Add ("Blue");
        pickerDataModel.Items.Add ("Red");
        pickerDataModel.Items.Add ("Purple");
        pickerDataModel.Items.Add ("White");

        // set it on our picker class
        //colorPicker = pickerDataModel;

        // wire up the value change method
        pickerDataModel.ValueChanged += (s, e) => {
            colorValueLabel.Text = pickerDataModel.SelectedItem;
        };

        // set our initial selection on the label
        colorValueLabel.Text = pickerDataModel.SelectedItem;
        //fin picker 
        base.ViewDidLoad ();}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following missing constructor to allow the class to be initialized from an unarchiver (i.e. your `.Storyboard` or `.nib`):

```
[Foundation.Export("initWithCoder:"]
public PickerDataModel(Foundation.NSCoder coder) { }
```

Comment: i added it in the pickerdatamodel class and it still throw the same error, should i cody this in other class?